# C# populate WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, db2, wpfdatagrid

I encountered a problem when I wanted to populate a WPF DataGrid using C#. In my XAML, I have created columns and bound my columns with my List of string that contains my data. Here is my code, can you tell me what I did wrong because it's been already 2 days and I am stuck?

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="ListeFiches" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="278" Margin="10,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="612" SelectionChanged="ListeFiches_SelectionChanged"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Progiciel" x:Name="prog" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="nbfiche" x:Name="nbfiche"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="etb" x:Name="etb" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Demandeur"  x:Name="Demand" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Correcteur" x:Name="correc"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRGM"  x:Name="PRGM" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="APP" x:Name="APP"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MOD" x:Name="MOD"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="OPT"  x:Name="OPT" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

**My CODE:**

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    if (conn != null)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("connexion établie");
       string qry = "SELECT * FROM DIITOOL.FICENT where MTPRO = 'G12' or MTPRO='URG' ";
       iDB2Command comm = conn.CreateCommand();
       comm.CommandText = qry;
       iDB2DataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          data.Add(reader[0].ToString() + reader[1].ToString() + reader[2].ToString() 
                    + reader[3].ToString() + reader[4].ToString() + reader[5].ToString() + reader[7].ToString()); 
       }
       ListeFiches.Items.Add(data);
       reader.Close();
       comm.Dispose();
       }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
       MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.ToString());
  }
```

and the blanks row are like this 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWriB.png)

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Why using code behind to populate data when this could be done a lot cleaner with MVVM?

Comment: l  at runtime on my datagrid it does display the nb of rows with my returned data but it doesnt display the content of the data.for example i have 3000 rows returned it does display 3000 blanks row on the datagrid

Comment: is this possible to program like column1.items = reader[0] ?

Comment: @aymannblal: What is `data`? How is it defined?

Comment: data is a list of string     that contains the result of the db2 sql query here its definition public static List<string> data = new List<string>() { };

Comment: and my Datagrid is called ListeFiches sorry it's rather incomplete above

Comment: @aymannblal please add xaml `DataGrid.Column`so we can check why its is displaying empty coloums in datagrid

Comment: @Avinash i just added it

Comment: In a data grid columns need to be bound to a property on the object which represents a row.

Comment: You need to create a class with a property for each column. Populate a list (or other collection of the class), bind the data grid to the list, and then bind the columns to the properties of the object.
I would suggest you follow a tutorial on the WPF data grid such as the Microsoft docs one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @aymannblal fellow any tutorial it will help u as there is so much to do